# github, changes are lost

Tags: git, github

I made several changes to my local github repository.

I tried to push:

```
git push --force origin
```

but now all changes are lost on my harddisk and the repository has the same look as my remote github, what can I do to get my last version back?

Comment: how did you lose the changes _locally_?  `git push` shouldn't do that.  (also, why were you using `--force`?)

Comment: what interface are you using (command line, gitextensions, Github desktop?)

Answer (score 1):

If you really *lost* your local repository and nobody else has a copy, then unfortunately there won’t be a way to recover your history. If you just *think* you have lost it locally but it’s still the same repository, chances are that you can reset to an older HEAD which actually still contains all your commits.

You can find that out by using `git reflog`. It will show you the changes to the HEAD pointer. If you see a commit that was your old version, you can reset your HEAD to that version by doing `git reset --hard HEAD@{n}` where `n` is the number from the reflog.

Comment: you saved me 1 hour of lost work. thanks a lot